# How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client, element

When I use embedded *javascript* *functions* I can get *client id* of elements with this code:

```
document.getElementById('<%=buttonXXX.ClientID%>' )
```

But now I am using *external javascript file* for caching and faster rendering
and this code does not work any more for getting *client id's* of elements, it gives error.

How can I get *client id's* of elements at *external javascript file* using
**asp.net 2.0 , netframework 3.5 , c# , iis 7.5**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I can suggest 2 ways.

### First way

define your variables before call the javascript, inside the **.aspx** file that can be compiled.

```
var ButtonXXXID = <%=buttonXXX.ClientID%>
// and now include your javascript and use the variable ButtonXXXID
```

### Second way

in the external javascript file, write your code as:

```
function oNameCls(ControlId1) {

    this.ControlId1 = ControlId1;

    this.DoYourWork1 = function() {
        // use the control id.
        // this.ControlId1
    }   
}
```

And call your actions like.

```
<script>
    // init - create
    var <%=this.ClientID%>MyCls = new oNameCls('<%=Control1.ClientID%>');
    // do your work
    <%=this.ClientID%>MyCls.DoYourWork1();
</script>
```

calling the action this way you prevent overwrite one action from one control with the same action from other controls on the same page.

Comment: @PokemonCraft, did you feel this answer 'solves' your problem? If so, click the little green checkmark : ) If not, give us some feedback so we can determine how to help you more.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a class selector. [jquery](http://jquery.com/) might greatly simplify your life here. So you could apply a special class to the control:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="foo" CssClass="foo" runat="server" Text="foo" />
```

and in your external javascript file once the DOM is ready you could reference the button using a class selector:

```
$(function() {
    var fooButton = $('.foo');
});
```

Comment: Darin Dimitrov thanks for answer but unfortunately i am not using jquery :( and do not know how to use. i think i will move my project to the asp.net 4.0 since it does support static ids :)

Comment: Hey Darin, a few years have gone by since you posted this, but thank you anyways.  It was a great, clean, elegant way to use class selectors instead of element id's to apply input masks to various elements in my website.

Answer (score 1):

in script file (`test.js`)

```
function test(ControlID1) {
  var controlId = document.getElementById(ControlID1);
  controlId.onchange = function () {        
    alert(controlId.value);
    }
  }
```

in `.aspx` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var callTest = test('<%=txtSelected.ClientID%>');
   window.onload = callTest;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in my `.js` file, when I have no other better choice.

```
$("[id$='buttonXXX'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I know old question but with jquery u can use this approache:

**Aspx file**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" ClientID="btnCalculate" runat="server" />
```

**external js file**

```
$("[ClientID='btnCalculate']").
```

https://lanitdev.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/extending-jquery-to-select-asp-controls/