# Access C# variable in javascript file .js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to create a javascript file with some C# variables? Something like this:

```
var foo =  <%= CODE_VALUE.foo %>;
```

Or do I have to create them in a usercontrol.ascx which I include in the `<head>` section?

Comment: If you tried it, you would find that this is indeed possible.

Comment: @GrahamClark well, it's not. Not in .js files anyway, unless you reconfigure IIS to process .js files with ASP.NET. Which would be an awful idea.

Comment: @Shedal, ah apologies, I didn't see the "javascript file" bit. Never mind!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not have this code inside the .js file because is not compile by asp.net and so is not translate the `CODE_VALUE.foo` into code.

what you can do is to place this variables just before load this .js file that you won to use, and set them on any aspx or user control.

For example

```
<script>
 var foo = <%=CODE_VALUE.foo%>;
<script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fileToUseTheFoo.js">   
</script>
```

alternative you can create a handler that read javascript files, include your custom variables and create a full javascript code as you like, and send it as javascript one.

Some relative: [How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file/3851247#3851247)

Comment: I like this! Why do I've never thought to do that!?

Comment: @SimoN I delete to not sound wired... :) what I mean is that this thinks is not so important because you are young and you have the time to discover them. What is important is to be open mind and happy with your life :)

Comment: No problem, I'm no that kind of guy who will be mad because you said I'm young ;) I'm am, but I still have 5 web years behind so I think it's not that bad :)

Comment: Five years is the university time, so is a life time on programming :)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use server side tags in .js files.
Instead create the variables on the pages/controls where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are static files, and served by the web server statically as well, without processing them with ASP.NET.

So if you really want to insert that value, you can create an empty .aspx page and include all the javascript in there, and then include the .aspx page in `script src`.

But I would probably prefer to have a web service instead, with a web method which you would call from javascript every time you need to receive the value.