# Javascript pass variable from vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have page index.asp in this file i have Vbscript function:

```
<%
Dim GetFromVbscript
GetFromVbscript = "hello"
%>
```

And javascript function

```
function SendFiltered() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Filtered.asp',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "<%=GetFromVbscript%>",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".center").html(data)
            }
        });
    };
```

It ok. It Post `"hello"`.

Now I need to run this javascript from external file so my index.asp now look like

```
<%
Dim GetFromVbscript
GetFromVbscript = "hello"
%>
<script src="js/SendFiltered.js"></script>
```

But now it Post `"<%=GetFromVbscript%>"`

So question is How to pass value or variable from VBscript to javascript?

Comment: make your `GetFromVbscript` variable `public`.

Comment: @MairajAhmad -- Public? Can you show sample? it will not help (imho).

when ASP preprocessor proceed ASP page it's proceed all ASP directive/command. JavaScript just including to output without any proceed. My opinion -- it's not possible.

Comment: yes i also tried this won't work i guess this will be only available in page.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331740/access-c-sharp-variable-in-javasciprt-file-js

Comment: "make Public Javascript variable", it's NOT the same as "public ASP variable".

Comment: You can also do like: <% Response.Write "<script>var GetFromVBscript='" & GetFromVBScript & "';</script>" <script src="js/SendFiltered.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ugly way but you can put .js extension in IIS's "Handler Mappings" by putting executable as %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll.