# How to get the id of a dynamic control in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file)

```
 var table = new Table { CssClass = "Table", ID = "MYTable" };
```

In the Javascript File Iwant to get the table ID which is like

```
'ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_MYTable.
```

How to get this Id in javascript.

Comment: since you don't know the id of that node, you'll have to find it by some other means (css classes? tree location?). Once you've got the node, getting the ID is trivial.

Comment: The standard solution is to bind something to the ClientID of the control.

Comment: `var id = '<%= MYTable.ClientID %>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script add this when you need the ID:

```
<%=table.ClientID%>
```