# How to use <%=control.ClientID%> in server control with embedded JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, custom-server-controls

I am creating a server control in a library project, which has javascript code, the javascript code need to get a button's ID, so I used <%= button.ClientID %>. Then I embed the javascript code as a file in the library project and use ScriptManager to add the script in CreateChildControls().

```
Dim sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page) 
sm.Scripts.Add(New ScriptReference("xxx.js", "LibraryProjectName"))
```

But when I run the page, it has a jquery parse error:invalid expression term '>'. So I am guessing the code has been generated but server doesn't convert <%= button.ClientID %> into generated ID format. So what should I do in this case?

Comment: `so I used <%= button.ClientID %>`...Can you show that code? Also, what does the source of the resulting HTML page look like?

Comment: It's because the js file isn't run through the .net runtime. It is serverd as is. In an aspx page the <%=... %> stuff is replaced by the result of the ... command but in a .js file it isnt. Maybe you could give it a class to use in jQuery for finding it like <a class="one two JSPleaseFindMe"... now you can find it with $(".JSPleaseFindme")

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file

Comment: I think just a suggestion, use `ClientIDMode = Static`, and access control like `$('#controlId')`

Comment: @HMR it does make sense, then I guess I could only use a specific class name for it. So any embedded or external JS file should use a precise id or class name? Because it doesn't go through server side?

Comment: The class name will prevent you from having spagetty co

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the buttons name set a very specific CSS class name:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMyGroovy" runat="server" CssClass="VerySpecific" Text="Action" />
```

Then use your `jQuery` Selector to get `$('.VerySpecific')` rather than the control name. Remember that items can have more than one class association. :)

You could make the selection more precise by selecting your server control CSS class eg.`.VerySpecificContainer` then selecting the instance of *.`VerySpecific`* contained by the control.

Answer (score 0):

It's usally a good approach to parameterize your external javascript file functions in such a way that they don't have to be on the page when using asp.net .

So you would have :

```
function foo (sender)
{
   return $(sender).val();
}
```

instead of

```
function foo ()
{
   return $("<%= sender.ClientID %>").val();
}
```

**On a side note:**

Did you know that you can set the id to be static if you are using Asp.Net 4 or above, that means the Id will match the name on server side and client side , then you don't need the <% %> tags to determine the id. This can be set in your web.config or in the page directive at the top of your apge.

Comment: ok, that would be great the server won't change the ID automatically, but you just have to be careful with the duplicated ID.

Answer (score 0):

in aspx file:

```
var serverPrefix ='<%= ClientID %>';
```

in js file:

```
function getServerId(id){
  if (typeof(serverPrefix ) != 'undefined')
  {
   return document.getElementById(prefix + '_' + id);
  }
  else
  {
   id;
  }
}
```

When you want to call some element, use like this:

```
$(getServerId('myTitleTxt')).text('hello!');
```

hope this help!