# Why my datepicker didn't change regional?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

My jquery version

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<link href="scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and this javascript code

```
$("#Textdate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
                             isBuddhist: true, defaultDate: toDay })
```

If have `defaultDate: toDay` when I click on textbox nothing happens, but If `toDay` change to `null`, It still an en calendar what I need to do ?

Comment: please check this link may be help you https://jqueryui.com/datepicker

Comment: I follow your link but My problem is about format in datepicker when I put deaultDate it will nothing happen

Comment: how you declare the TextDate2 asp net text control ?

Comment: @Aristos yes bro , It asp.net text control  , didn't work ?

Comment: Add your html please. Make sure your instanciation of datepicker is done after the jquery import and when your document is ready

Comment: @Alexis can you give me example ?

Comment: use simple jquery datetime picker with adding class name to textbox

Comment: @BeaterBallKpm Add your whole code please. Can't help you with small parts and without all your html

Comment: @Alexis All of font end ?

Comment: @BeaterBallKpm your input datepicker and the order of your code: example `<script src="jquery"></script> [Code not important here]  <input class="datepicker">[code] <script></script>`

Comment: This is all
`$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Textdate2").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', isBuddhist: true, defaultDate: null })
        });`
`<asp:TextBox ID="Textdate2" runat="server" Width="30%" Height="5%"  ></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net the Id of the control is change when is render on page, so with this code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textdate2" runat="server" Width="30%" Height="5%" ></asp:TextBox>
```

you need to write

```
$("#<%=Textdate2.ClientID%>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
                             isBuddhist: true, defaultDate: toDay })
```

to actually capture it.

Related:
[Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)
[How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file/3851247#3851247)

Comment: @BeaterBallKpm can you open the browser tools to see if you have javascript errors ?

Comment: thank you for your recommend, I find the way to fix now

Answer (score -1):

may be u dint add the html or library missing please check

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', isBuddhist: true, 
defaultDate: new Date()})

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm following your code chane defaultDate: toDay to new Date but It not a buddhist calendar