# Bootstrap Jquery Filter not working, when i use master page in asp.net. Its works fine in simpe webforms

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

When i use webform it works fine. but with master page it's not wroking, i provided almost all code here.

there is a textbox and a table. purpose is to Search using any keyword.

there are 3 files links which i also linked in my master page

[theme.css](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sE_g21NW44gC_Avx0MMAhfdbXKbyWQly)

[dashboard.css](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uErzBYu9fYWNWXsQXASF8dyUYJvxbU6p)

[theme.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GVPiauKNld6vxfrDFlGe3HeLP2JMmsBN)

Here is Master Page

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Master Page</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link id="themecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Web Form With Master Page

```
<%@ Page Title="FJ - DashBoard | Company" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Company.aspx.cs" Inherits="FJ_System.Company1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="js/Search.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center" style="font-size: large"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>Company Details</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:TextBox ID="myInput" Style="text-align: center; font: bold; font-size: large" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
                    <thead style="text-align-last: center; background-color: black; color: white">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Adress</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Opening Balance</th>
                            <th>Salesman</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="myTable" style="text-align: center;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Umair</td>
                            <td>latifabad</td>
                            <td>Hyderabad</td>
                            <td>15000</td>
                            <td>David</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Farzan</td>
                            <td>Unitno4</td>
                            <td>Hyderabad</td>
                            <td>15000</td>
                            <td>Parker</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Huzaifa</td>
                            <td>Malir</td>
                            <td>Karachi</td>
                            <td>20000</td>
                            <td>Salman</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Search.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
   });
});
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Check the html. `myInput` is probably something like `ContentPlaceHolder1_myInput`. Or use `ClientID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendered id is not always the same as you type it, especial when you add it on master page. To get the rendered on page id from `<asp:TextBox ID="myInput" Style="text-align: center;...` you must use the `.ClientID` as

```
 $("#<%=myInput.ClientID%>").on("keyup", function () {
```

the full code will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#<%=myInput.ClientID%>").on("keyup", function () {
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
   });
});
```

note that the `myTable` is not asp.net control, so we left it as it is

You can also read about 
[Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)

### Update

If you have this code out side of asp.net them its not going to work because you can not find the id, neither render it.
Move this javascript code inside the page, or render the ids before you load this code and use that ids in the external code like this example

[How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file/3851247#3851247)

Comment: i tried with $("#<%=myInput.ClientID%>").on("keyup", function () {    but it's not working.  ContentPlaceHolder1_myInput   this one works.

Comment: @UmairFarooq It works if you add it inside asp.net page. If you have it on .js file of course is not work, is not render the id, neither is logical to add this small part of code outside of asp.net...

Comment: Perfect... Yes, You were right :) Thanks For The Info.